# cuando oprimo el botón comprar me aparece por consola, solo el primer objeto del array, como hago para que aparezcan los otros y no siempre el mismo

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**funcion que si logra añadir la cantidad, pero siempre me pone el primer objeto aunque con el botón comprar seleccione otro, la idea es que aparesca por consola el que seleccione

**

```js
const mostarcantidad = () => {

  var cantidad = parseFloat(document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML)

  cantidad = cantidad + 1;

  document.getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = cantidad;

  let productosSeleccionados = document.querySelector("#btn1");


  let productosComprados = postres.find(elemento => elemento.nombre.includes(productosSeleccionados.value))

  let carrito = []

  carrito.push(productosComprados)

  console.log("carrito", carrito)

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->



<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
 <div class="d-grid gap-2">
   <button class="btn1 btn-primary button " id="btn1" onclick=mostarcantidad()>Comprar</a>
 </div>
```

```
  localStorage.setItem('productos seleccionados', JSON.stringify(carrito));

}
```

```html
 <div class="d-grid gap-2">
   <button class="btn1 btn-primary button " id="btn1" onclick=mostarcantidad()>Comprar</a>
 </div>
```

```html
 <span class="position absolute top-20 start-70 translate-middle bagde rounded-pill bg-danger" >
             0
         </span>
```

Comment: Falta algo de información, puedes incorporar a la pregunta la estructura de la variable productosSeleccionados?

Comment: hola vicent ahi le agregue mas informacion para que quede mas claro....ahora cuando cuando oprimo cual fuese la opcion de compra en consola siempre me sigue mostrando del array const postre el primer objeto.